# How to get response from adv7513 i2c

Tags: vhdl, fpga, i2c, hdmi

I want to use hdmi monitor with cyclone V GX board, but I don't get an acknowledgement from [adv7513](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADV7513.pdf) on i2c bus.

I think there is a problem with the address that I am sending at the beginning of the i2c transaction (I get no acknowledgement of address) I couldn't find information on whether PD/AD is low or high. Also I am not sure if i should use 7 or 8 bit address, so I would like some explanation.

I used i2c controller that i found online:
https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10125324

[signaltap result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrvuU.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried yourself to debug this problem or to find out which address should be used?

Comment: I've simulated my code and used signaltap. I've added  waveform from logic analyzer to the question

Answer (score 1):

I assume you haven't read the [ADV7513 Programming Guide](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/ADV7513_Programming_Guide.pdf)

> The ADV7513 uses four I2C register maps. The SDA/SCL programming
>   address for the Main Register Map is 0x72 or 0x7A, based on whether
>   PD/AD is pulled high (10KΩ resistor to power supply = 0x7A) or pulled
>   low (10KΩ resistor to GND = 0x72) when power is applied to the
>   supplies. The user should wait 200ms for the address to be decided,
>   after the power supplies are high, before attempting to communicate
>   with the ADV7513 using I2C

I2C addresses are 7-bit or 10-bit not 8-bit. In this case it is 7-bit. 
See [I2C Specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf). So if PD/AD is high, 7-bit address is 0x7A. In binary your 7 bits will be: `1111010`. The R/W bit is the last bit of the first I2C 'address' byte but the vhd code you posted doesn't need that as part of the address, that's done separately.

```
addr      : IN     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0); --address of target slave
rw        : IN     STD_LOGIC;                    --'0' is write, '1' is read
```

If you are still having problems, check your [pull-ups](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/is-there-a-correct-resistance-value-for-i2c-pull-up-resistors), I2C SCL clock rate, ensure the master allows clock stretching. The VHDL code you posted has quite a lot of information about how to use so re-read that.

Alternatively take to question to [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and take some oscilloscope readings of SDA/SCL.

Comment: My adv7513 is mounted on cyclone v development board, so I'am certain that it's connected  correctly with my fpga

Comment: I've changed address to 0111001 and it started working